# C# Array of anonymous class inside another anonymous class

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I deserialize a JSon string that holds an object with an array of subobjects.
The current working solution looks like this:

```
var definition = new { systems = new subclass[0] };
var ret = JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(source, definition);

public class subclass
{
    public long id;
}
```

**Is there a way to replace the subclass with another anonymous one?**
I tried using the following, but only get a compiler error:

```
var definition = new { constellations = new{ id=0L }[0] };
```

Comment: Use [Dynamic](https://www.dotnetperls.com/dynamic)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wonder if you could do:

```
var definition = new { systems = MakeEmptyArrayFrom(new { id = 0L}) };
...
static T[] MakeEmptyArrayFrom<T>(T value) => new T[0];
```

note: if that works, it will probably also work even if you use something like:

```
static T[] MakeNullArrayFrom<T>(T value) => null;
```

as I imagine the library is more interested in the `Type` than the value.

Comment: Yes, it works. Even the null version. As I have multiple of these it will help declutter the code